"Device not configured" after external HD improperly unmounted
I accidently unplugged my external HD before the eject was done :-/
/Volumes/Red is still there and can't be deleted.
The HD still mounts but as /Volumes/Red 1.
How can I remove /Volumes/Red?
$ gls -lhA /Volumes/

gls: cannot access '/Volumes/Red': Device not configured
d????????? ? ?    ?       ?                ?  Red


Info: macOS Ventura 13.6.7
